# EaselJS hide part of paint stroke outside boundary

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, drawing, easeljs

I'm trying to create a coloring book using EaselJS similar to this example:

https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/examples/CurveTo.html

However, I have discontinuous shapes I want users to color, and I want to hide paint strokes outside the shapes while allowing them to initiate a stroke outside of the shape. If they do start drawing outside the allowed space, I still want the part of the path within boundaries to be displayed.

[to see what i mean click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOv3H.png)

My first idea is to use a full canvas and cover the parts not colorable with an svg filled with the background color, but that would involve having to pass a click event on the svg to the same pixel on the canvas it's covering.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: use a clipPath or if you want to pass through events pointer-events: none will hep.

Comment: In EaselJS you can use another shape as a "mask", which uses the clipPath @RobertLongson suggested.